# Meaning of a sentence that is little confusing

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

I initially asked the question of what is the meaning of "accurate to within" on this website and got answers. I couldn't understand what they were trying to say but thought I understood the examples they gave me. A sentence from one of the answer was:

> It means that the accuracy is measurable within a range of that size.

I couldn't understand the "accuracy is measurable..." part. I need some help.

Comment: I'd recommend you either revise your previous question or include a comment requesting clarification from the answerer. Otherwise this might get closed as a duplicate. At the very least you should include a link to your previous question so we can see the context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of a confusing phrase](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/311424/meaning-of-a-confusing-phrase)

Comment: Sorry, i didn't think of linking my previous question. I will do it now

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/311424/meaning-of-a-confusing-phrase

Answer (score -1):

Reading the original question and answer, I suggest you use the examples to understand the meaning of "accurate within", and not focus too much on the quoted sentence.

"The accuracy is measurable within a range of that size" isn't a sentence anyone would say, since they'd just say "accurate within". It's an example of the often awkward constructions that show up in definitions when the word or phrase we are defining doesn't have any obvious synonyms.